# Rerun Ruby test suite with feature flag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class with 20 rspec tests, and the result should be the exact same whether my main logic goes through a feature flag or not.

I am wondering what the best way to test this suite so that on Jenkins it can test both directions?
I want to avoid having to copy paste the 20 tests again, just to add another line like:

`featureFlag.enabled = True`
Right before the test logic.

Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends which test framework you use? RSpec? Minitest?

In RSpec you could for instance use a shared example

```
RSpec.shared_examples "some example" do |flag|
  before do
    featureFlag.enabled = flag
  end

  it "works with feature flag '#{flag}'" do
    expect(something).to be true
  end
end

RSpec.describe SomeClass do
  include_examples "some example", true
  include_examples "some example", false
end
```

In Minitest you can just use a module.

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples